# What method of UIView gets called when instantiated from a NIB?

Tags: iphone, uiview, custom-view

I have a simple custom view that is connected via outlet to a NIB. For this particular view, there are actions that I would like to perform on the view when it is initialized, no matter what NIB it is on.

Trouble is, neither the (id)init or the (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame methods are getting called on the custom view.

Which method gets called on a UIView when it is instantiated from a NIB? I would just use the view controller and viewDidLoad method except that this particular view appears on a lot of different NIBs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `awakeFromNib` for this kind of initialization. The regular initialization methods are called when the object is actually created by IB and then archived using `NSCoding`, so those methods are never called within your application. You could also override `initWithCoder:` which will be called, but I don't recommend it since other outlets may not be wired at that point.

Comment: Perfect! For some reason I thought awakeFromNib was limited to UIViewController - once again, this proves that sometimes all it takes is a second pair of eyes :)

Comment: @retailevolved: Yeah, when a nib file is loaded, every object in the nib file that is unarchived (except for proxy objects--since those are not actually unarchived from the nib) will be sent an awakeFromNib message after all objects have been unarchived and all outlets have been wired.